# Access list variables from load_yaml block in SaltStack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have my state file as below.

```
{% load_yaml as test %}
    value:
      val1: 'string1'
      val2: 'string2'
    value1: ['sub1','sub2']
{% endload %}
```

When I'm trying to access **val1** variable as below there is no issue but accessing values of **value1** list could not. Any help on this.

```
access val1 variable:
cmd.run:
  - name: echo {{ test.value.val1 }}
```

Accessing value1 as below throws error.

```
{% set test2 = test.value1 %}

access value1 variable:
cmd.run:
  - name: echo {{ test2 }}
```

Error as....

```
   Data failed to compile:
-------
   ID access the value1 variable in SLS is not a dictionary
-------
   ID cmd.run in SLS is not a dictionary
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the indentation in the state for `cmd.run`. This is what the error is complaining about.

The example below can access the variables fine, and the respective values are shown in the output when the state is run.

```yaml
# Note the indentation below for "cmd.run"
show-val1-variable:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "echo {{ test.value.val1 }}"

{% set test2 = test.value1 %}

show-test2-variable:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "echo {{ test2 }}"
```

Comment: Thanks !! how come i have missed such a little thing...

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped!